# How to print only a certain part of elements from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

So I have a list:

```
['13:57:09.273 0,Type=IsXover Count=4,mcuTs=0x000265C7,lp-isD=1',
 '13:57:09.341 1,Type=Xover Count=47,mcuTs=0x0002660A,lp-isD=0',
 '13:57:15.389 0,Type=Xover Count=48,mcuTs=0x00027D87,lp-isD=1']
```

I wanna do something like looking for 'over' in each element and then printing a string starting from 'over' until the next comma. so the result should look like this:

```
['over Count=4','over Count=47','over Count=48']
```

I could do this using 'rfind()' if I was directly reading from a file but since lists don't have 'rfind()' I was wondering if there is another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
list = ['13:57:09.273 0,Type=IsXover Count=4,mcuTs=0x000265C7,lp-isD=1', 
    '13:57:09.341 1,Type=Xover Count=47,mcuTs=0x0002660A,lp-isD=0',
    '13:57:15.389 0,Type=Xover Count=48,mcuTs=0x00027D87,lp-isD=1']

result = []
for string in list:
    for index, sub_string in enumerate(string.split(',')):
        if index == 1:
           result.append(sub_string[sub_string.find('over'):])

print(result)
```

A list comprehension version of this code would not be as readable as the code above, but here it is either way:

```
result = [sub_string[sub_string.find('over'):] for string in list for index, sub_string in enumerate(sub_string.split(',')) if index == 1]
print(result)
```

Both code snippets will give the desired result of

```
['over Count=4','over Count=47','over Count=48']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to solve the problem:

```
import re

Structure = ['13:57:09.273 0,Type=IsXover Count=4,mcuTs=0x000265C7,lp-isD=1', 
        '13:57:09.341 1,Type=Xover Count=47,mcuTs=0x0002660A,lp-isD=0',
        '13:57:15.389 0,Type=Xover Count=48,mcuTs=0x00027D87,lp-isD=1']

Counts = []
for element in Structure:
    sub_array = element.split(",")
    valid = re.match(r"^.*(over Count=(\d+))", sub_array[1].strip())
    Counts.append(valid.group(1))

print(Counts)
```

Which would print:

```
['over Count=4', 'over Count=47', 'over Count=48']
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex, we can use string methods:

```
a = ['13:57:09.273 0,Type=IsXover Count=4,mcuTs=0x000265C7,lp-isD=1',
     '13:57:09.341 1,Type=Xover Count=47,mcuTs=0x0002660A,lp-isD=0',
     '13:57:15.389 0,Type=Xover Count=48,mcuTs=0x00027D87,lp-isD=1']
b = []
for s in a:
    i1 = s.find('over')
    i2 = s.find(',', i1)
    b.append(s[i1:i2])
print(b)
```

gives

```
['over Count=4', 'over Count=47', 'over Count=48']
```

Or, if you want a one-line list comprehension:

```
[s[s.find('over'):s.find(',', s.find('over'))] for s in a]
```

The trick here is that the [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method of the string returns the index of the start of the given substring, and if we provide a second argument, the search starts from that integer.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you out

```
itemList  = ['13:57:09.273 0,Type=IsXover Count=4,mcuTs=0x000265C7,lp-isD=1',
 '13:57:09.341 1,Type=Xover Count=47,mcuTs=0x0002660A,lp-isD=0',
 '13:57:15.389 0,Type=Xover Count=48,mcuTs=0x00027D87,lp-isD=1']

for item in itemList:
    if ‘over’ in item:
        indexi = item.find(‘over’)
        indexy = item.find(‘,mcuTs’)
        print(item[indexi:indexy]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` twice and concatenate the result with `over`:

```
inList = ['13:57:09.273 0,Type=IsXover Count=4,mcuTs=0x000265C7,lp-isD=1',
 '13:57:09.341 1,Type=Xover Count=47,mcuTs=0x0002660A,lp-isD=0',
 '13:57:15.389 0,Type=Xover Count=48,mcuTs=0x00027D87,lp-isD=1']

newList = ['over' + elem.split(',')[1].split('over')[1] for elem in inList]
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['over Count=4', 'over Count=47', 'over Count=48']
```